# Mqtt Node mcu connection Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, iot

So I have this 2 files I created in Node JS:

Broker:

```
const mosca = require('mosca');

const broker = new mosca.Server({
    port: 9000
});

broker.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Broker is ready!');
})

broker.on('clientConnected', (client) => {
    console.log('Client connected', client.id);
});

broker.on('published', (packet, client) => {
    console.log('Published', packet.payload.toString());
});
```

Pub:

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt');
const SerialPort = require('serialport');

const port = new SerialPort('COM4', {
    baudRate: 9600
});

const parser = port.pipe(new SerialPort.parsers.Readline({ delimiter: '\n' }));

const pub = mqtt.connect('mqtt://localhost:9000');

pub.on('connect', () => {
    parser.on('data', (data) => {
        pub.publish('topic test', data);
    });
});
```

But when I run pub i get this error:
const port = new SerialPort('COM4', {
^

TypeError: SerialPort is not a constructor

But I have already installed all the libraries, so I don't know what to do.

Comment: It looks like you are using v10+ of [serialport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport) with the v9 API - see the [upgrade guide](https://serialport.io/docs/guide-upgrade#serialport-package) (i.e. `const { SerialPort } = require('serialport')`).